# PHP in external javascript file causing it to not load

Tags: javascript, php

Exactly what the title says. I originally had a lot of javascript in my index.php file and when I attempted to put it in an external js file and load it like I did with other js files, the file did not load. When I look at the js file in my editor it shows errors every time there is php code. How do I work around this issue?

1. I have tried renaming it as a php file and that didn't work (I get errors everywhere).
2. The reason I have php code in there is because there are a lot of "if" statements that check different things about signed in user e.g. `<?php if (Auth::instance()->current_user()): ?>` . I also add and update mysql table based on different events e.g. clicking a button.
3. Everything works fine if I have code directly in  tags in index.php file.
4. When I remove php from js file then the external file works (no surprise there) both in .js and .php forms.

Thanks

Comment: php won't parse in a js file. You should post code to show what you're trying to do. we may be able to offer a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do, is have js files without any php code in them.

Then in php, create a javascript as follow :

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
var env = {'current_user':JSON.parse(<?=json_encode(Auth::instance()->current_user())?>), 'foo':'bar'}
console.log(env); //remove this before deploying in production
</script>
</script type='text/javascript' src='yourscript.js'></script>
<!--  other scripts here -->
</head>
...
```

Now you can use the global `env` variable in all your scripts to access your user informations (check console for details : F12 - console tab, then reload.)

in `env.current_user` you'll have all your user informations.

Note that you may want to filter that because in this example, any aknowledged user could access its information on client side.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Loïc for answering. Is this preferable to just using: <?php include 'myjavascript.php'; ?> . If so, why? Thanks again

Comment: Yes it is, because your javascript will be cached by the browser, only the variables are changing. So clients will gain in speed, and your server will have less overall load.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense! On a side note re filtering out code, can you recommend a good resource (e.g. a book) on general security with php. It is not covered very well in any of the books I have. @Loïc

Comment: it's common sense, just give the client the information he really needs, and before saving or showing whatever the client sent you, clean it. a good resource on the subject is OWASP : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Attack